# Clojure: multiple let bindings

Tags: clojure

In Java, I usually do this,

```
MyObject o1 = new MyObject();
o1.doSomething();
MyObject o2 = new MyObject();
o2.doWith(o1);
MyObject o3 = new MyObject();
o3.doWithBoth(o1, o2);
```

In Clojure, if I use let bindings, it might look like,

```
(let [o1 (create-obj)]
  (.doSomething o1)
  (let [o2 (create-obj)]
    (.doWith o2 o1)
    (let [o3 (create-obj)]
      (.doWithBoth o3 o1 o2))))
```

The code grows to the right hand side which is ugly and hard to maintain. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
(let [o1 (doto (create-obj) (.doSomething))
      o2 (doto (create-obj) (.doWith o1))
      o3 (doto (create-obj) (.doWithBoth o1 o2))]
  ...)
```

See `(doc doto)` for details.

*(Update:)* This works because in each case it is the newly created object that you're calling a method on. If instead you wanted to call a function / method with the newly created object passed in in an argument position other than the first one, you'd probably be best served by the `_` trick described by noisesmith, though you could use `doto` with `as->`. The latter has the advantage of not introducing an unused local which would not be cleared (last time I checked Clojure only cleared locals that were actually referred to in subsequent code), but that's of course of no consequence if you're calling `void`-returning methods for side effect.

Comment: It transforms `(as-> expr sym form1 form2 ...)` into `(let [sym expr sym form1 sym form2 ...] sym)`. See `(doc as->)` at the REPL (>= 1.5.0) or follow [this link](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/as->) to see the same on the Clojure API page. (I couldn't find a stable link to the 1.5.x API, so I'm linking to "current" instead.)

Comment: Just to be clear, you'd use `as->` inside `doto`: `(doto 1 (as-> foo (+ foo 2) (* foo 3) (println foo)))` prints 9 and returns 1.

Comment: Can I suggest (new MyObject) in place of (create-obj)? "Idiomatic Clojure code calls Java libraries directly" Halloway.

Answer (score 3):

The standard idiom is to use `_` as the let binding for lines evaluated for side effects.

```
(let [o1 (create-obj)
      _ (.doSomething o1)
      o2 (create-obj)
      _ (.doWith o2 o1)
      o3 (create-obj)]
  (.doWithBoth o3 o1 o2))
```

Answer (score 3):

The following (my) solution is viable but in poor taste. The `.dosomething` &c method calls no doubt mutate the objects they are applied to. So what we are doing is constructing an object, binding it to a local name, and then mutating it behind the scenes. Eugh!

Michal Marczyck's answer is preferable, because `doto` returns the mutated object, which is then bound to the local name and never mutated thereafter.

We can't expect Java interop to comply with Clojure idioms, but we should try to flag infractions, as `doto` does here.

---

`let` bindings are made left to right. So you can do the above with one of them:

```
(let [o1 (create-obj)
      _ (.doSomething o1)
      o2 (create-obj)
      _ (.doWith o2 o1)
      o3 (create-obj)]
        (.doWithBoth o3 o1 o2))
```

Here we bind `_` twice. It's the conventional name for an ignored binding. Presumably, `.doSomething`, `.doWith`, and `.doWithBoth` are performed for side-effects.